# Using Masstransit Exchange is getting created for contract and implementing , even though ConfigureConsumeTopology = false

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

Implementation of Masstransit using RabbitMQ

In Publisher

```
 cfg.Message\<IEntityMessage\>(x =\> x.SetEntityName("ExchangeName"));
```

```
public class EntityMessage: IEntityMessage
```

In Consumer

```
    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("QueueName", c =\>   
    {
        c.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
        c.ConfigureConsumer\<EntityMessage\>(context);
        c.Bind("ExchangeName");
    });
```

How can i set the same exchange name for all my entitites.

========= Updated

My Event Bus has IEntityMessage interface and has properties.
In publisher Iam having implementation of this IEntityMessage as EntityMessage and my publishing project has a configuration as below,

```
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
            {
                config.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Host"], "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Username"]);
                        h.Password(configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Password"]);
                    });

                    cfg.Message<IEntityMessage>(x => x.SetEntityName("ExchangeName"));
                                     
                    
                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("QueueName", c =>    //In order to subscribe the queue.
                    {
                        c.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                        c.ConfigureConsumer<OtherEntityConsumer>(context);
                        c.Bind("ExchangeName");
                    });
                });
            });
            return services;
```

Consumer has,

```
services.AddMassTransit(config =>
            {
                config.AddConsumer<EntityMessageConsumer>(typeof(IEquipmentCreatedMessage));
}

cfg.Host(configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Host"], "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Username"]);
                        h.Password(configuration["RabbitMQConnection:Password"]);
});
                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("ExchangeName", c =>    //In order to subscribe the queue.
                    {
                        c.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                        c.ConfigureConsumer<EntityMessageConsumer>(context);
                        c.Bind("ExchangeName");
                    });
```

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous, if you have an actual example please update the question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the same exchange name for all of your message types, and even if you somehow decide to try and do it anyway, you can't have a message type exchange name that is the same as the receive endpoint name (QueueName in your example).

Comment: Like this EntityMessage I have around 10 entities, for which i want to have same exchange, @ChrisPatterson, is it a good idea to have same excahnge and same queues for all entities in my microservice. I am trying to give the entity name as the exchange name so that it will create a single exchange for all my entities

Comment: Well, as I stated in my answer, I would not put all my entities in a single exchange, and don't recommend anyone else do it either.

Comment: Is it Ok if my application has 40 entities and they are having different exchanges and all exchanges are bing to the same Queue. Or do they need to have the different Queues

Comment: I would never put all my consumers on one queue. You might [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsUlQ93j2MY) to get my perspective.